# ...дались тебе эти макароны!

Tags: грамматика, этимология, выражения

Как вообще возник оборот "далось тебе [это] XXX" ? Почему он означает то, что означает?

Т.е. я его использую, нутром ощущаю, но логически разложить этот оборот на составляющие, объяснить его механику - не могу.

Comment: > Даться - стать предметом внимания/интереса. Чуть более подробно есть вот здесь - [Значение слова «даться»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)

Answer (score 1):

Нравится мне в этих восклицательных выражениях то, что по факту они всегда скрывают вопрос 'зачем?', на который мы как правило и отвечаем после этого восклика.

Интуитивно, я не филолог: в самом деле, зачем мне эти макароны? Смотрю на слово 'дались' и первым делом вспоминаю, что я так же слышу 'ну **с**дались тебе эти макароны!'. 'Дались' и 'сдались', которые никак не меняют смысла предложения, видимо потому что имеют нечто общее. 'Дались' и 'сдались'. Сами. Мне. Словно я ничего не сделал для их получения, как будто это нахаляву. И вот тогда становится сразу понятно, 'зачем'

Answer (score 1):

Как сказал @makaleks, скорее всего это искажённое "сдалисть".
А "сдаться" означает в том числе "понадобиться".

"Понадобились тебе эти макароны!" - удивление или неудовольствие от этого факта.

Comment: Это просто переводить вопрос на другое слово, а сам вопрос остаётся. Вопрос ведь был про этимологию, историю языка, "как возник оборот...?"

Comment: Нет же, я не считаю одно слово искажением другого. Ещё раз, я взял лишь 2 приемлемых варианта и заметил, что общее в них - самостоятельность, что собеседник получает нечто даром. Добавить сюда практику объясняться в причине в ответ на этот выпад - получим в грубой форме 'ну зачем? халява, что ли?'

Comment: @makaleks - типа "чемодана без ручки", ни тащить ни бросить?

Comment: @Arioch, да, вроде того. Только с точки зрения восклицающего - ведь он может не понимать ценность 'макарон'/чего-либо ещё

Comment: Вы точно помните, откуда эта цитата? В оригинале всё понятно и про ценность макарон, и про их последствия.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример из литературы [Евгений Евтушенко. Ягодные места (1982)]

Герой с удовольствием собирает грибы, а его другу это надоело, и он говорит:

"Дались тебе эти грибы, спина уж от них болит."

***Дались тебе***... ― это разговорный фразеологизм, он широко применяется в речи. Как же он возник?   Да очень просто, это результат  **развития значения слова, о чем говорится в толковом словаре.**

(1) ***Собака не дается в руки*** (не даёт   что-л. сделать с собой, она недоступна).

(2) ***Ему хорошо дается математика*** (она для него доступна).

(3)  ***Далась ему эта математика*** ,  он только о ней и говорит.

**Схематично это выглядит так**: реальный предмет (дается или не дается) ― отвлеченное понятие (дается или не дается) ― **ироническое прочтение**, в результате чего  **положительная оценка переходит в отрицательную.**

**ДАТЬСЯ,** св. Разг. **1. Позволить схватить себя**; допустить сделать что-л. с собой; поддаться, уступить. Не дамся в руки. **2. только 3 л. (кому). Явиться, оказаться** каким-л. для овладения,  понимания и т.п. Латынь ему не даётся. Грамота далась ему легко. 3. **только прош. 3 л. (кому)**. **Стать предметом крайнего внимания, интереса, постоянных разговоров кого-л.** Далась тебе эта песенка.

Толковый словарь: [http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=даться&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&all=x)

Comment: Типа, носится с математикой, как дурак с торбой? Что-то в этом есть, интересная версия. Хотя мне 2 кажется исходно разговорным сокращением от "поддаётся". Аналогично "Дубинушке", которая "сама пойдёт, сама пойдёт". И поэтому переход 2-3 для меня не очевиден. Если он был (когда?), то должен остаться набор текстов, где новый смысл чем дальше, тем больше заменяет в использовании старый. Как был переход смысла в слове "наверное" (до наоборот), смена основного смысла слова "отойти" (...с миром или просто куда-то)

Comment: Это не совсем версия, материал взят из толкового словаря русского языка (там указаны все три значения). Я  немного поправлю ответ, чтобы он был понятнее.

Comment: в словарях даётся именно ЗНАЧЕНИЕ, как оно устоялось на сегодня. Но значение тут и так все знают, даже если ощущают немного по разному. Вопрос-то именно в ПРОИСХОЖДЕНИИ одного из значений. А этого в словарях нет. Ну например, во всех ли словарях указано ПРОИСХОЖДЕНИЕ выражения "в этой связ'и", которое случилось у нас на глазах.

Comment: У многозначных слов  второе и все прочие значения могут развиваться способом переноса, то есть по происхождению являются языковыми метафорами.  Интересующее нас третье значение   слова связано с иронией, когда под маской обычного  скрывается насмешливо-отрицательное отношение к предмету или явлению. В словаре указано значение, но не указан ПЕРЕХОД к этому значению, поэтому это моя ВЕРСИЯ. Вы можете с ней согласиться или выдвинуть свою.

Answer (score -3):

Даться -- разговорный и просторечный вариант слова "понадобиться". "Далось тебе это?" - Зачем тебе это понадобилось? Не нужно тебе это!

Comment: я не согласен - разумеется это однокоренные слова, но для того, чтобы утверждать, что одно - просторечный вариант другого, нужны какие-то источники )

Comment: помилуйте, корень **даться -> дат/дай/дав**, также как и в слове **удачный** (от гл. удаться), корень **понадобиться -> доб**, также как и в слове **удобный**, и очевидно, что прилагательные **удачный** и **удобный** разнокоренные